# CSS rotateY(0deg) makes jQuery.animate() work better in Chrome Android

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I have just spotted that elements which have *transform:rotateY(0deg)* runs smoother when animated with jQuery.animate() method then the elements that does not have this rule. I got my eyes wide open when i realized it.

```
div {
top: 0px;
width: 15px;
height: 15px;
padding: 0;
}

.smooth {
 transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

<div ></div>
<div class='smooth'></div>
```

And when animated with for example:

```
$('div').animate({top: "+=100"},100);
```

The second div will animate smoother. The rotateY(0deg) probably is one of the options which cause this, but i discovered this with it.

Can anyone tell me why it works like that? Is it common among the developers to do such things? I have tried to improve the look of the animation for a long time, and this is the solution which improved my animations most.

Tested on LG G2 Chrome Android.

Comment: It's possible that adding a `rotateY` rule causes the element transformations to be offloaded to the GPU. See http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/increase-your-sites-performance-with-hardware-accelerated-css or similar resources around CSS hardware acceleration or using the GPU to increase CSS rendering performance.